# TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined -- in ngAfterViewChecked

Tags: angular, angular7, karma-jasmine

Some of my karma jasmine unit tests are failing after I added an ngAfterViewChecked. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I tried initializing the below "mySwitchEl" but still got the same error.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my.component.html'
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewChecked {

   @ViewChild('myswitch') mySwitchEl: ElementRef;

   public somethingEnabled: boolean;

   public switchWidth: number;

   constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { 
   }

   ngOnInit(): void { 
      // do stuff 
   }

   ngOnDestory(): void {
      // do stuff 
   }

   ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
      this.switchWidth = this.mySwitchEl.nativeElement.offsetWidth * 2;
      this.cd.detectChanges();
   }

}
```

Here is the unit test. If I put "fixture.detectChanges" in the beforeEach, all of my unit tests fail instead of only a few.

```
    import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('myswitch') mySwitchEl: ElementRef;

   public somethingEnabled: boolean;

   public switchWidth: number;

   constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { 
   }

   ngOnInit(): void { 
      // do stuff 
   }

   ngOnDestory(): void {
      // do stuff 
   }

   ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
      this.switchWidth = this.mySwitchEl.nativeElement.offsetWidth * 2;
      this.cd.detectChanges();
   }
}
```

Sample of the html

```
<label class="switch-light" [style.width.px]="switchWidth">
   <a class="btn btn-primary" id="my-switch-identifier" #myswitch>
      Some Text Here
   </a>
</label>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This code doesn't compile, `this.alertsSwitchEl` is accessed inside `ngAfterViewChecked` but it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: @uminder - sorry, I changed the variable names when I posted. this.alertsSwitchEl was supposed to be "mySwitchEl". Updated my post

Comment: The above code works fine. There might be something wrong elsewhere. Create a stackblitz.

Comment: @MaihanNijat - The code works, but the unit test is failing for me. The unit test is working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a conditional statement to ngAfterViewChecked()

```
    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
      if(this.mySwitchEl) {
         this.switchWidth = this.mySwitchEl.nativeElement.offsetWidth * 2;
         this.cd.detectChanges();
      }
   }
```